# Apache camel to invoke ejb 2

Tags: apache-camel, ejb-2.x

Can I use apache camel to invoke remote ejbs (ejb2.0)? How do I pass parameters to these ejsb? The example given on the camel website is not very clear. Also I'm not using spring. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call remote EJBs you can just use Java code, and let Camel call your java code.

If you want to try the camel-ejb component, then you need to configure the component for remote EJBs which is not so easy - there is a JIRA ticket to improve this in a future release.

So I suggest to just use Java code - eg just call these remote EJBs as you would do from regular Java code without using Apache Camel.